# What is the correct approach to test classes with inheritance?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

Assuming I have the following (over-simplified) class structure:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    Base(int valueForFoo) : foo(valueForFoo) { };
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    int doThings() { return foo; };
    int doOtherThings() { return 42; };

  protected:
    int foo;
}

class BarDerived : public Base
{
  public:
    BarDerived() : Base(12) { };
    ~BarDerived() { };
    int doBarThings() { return foo + 1; };
}

class BazDerived : public Base
{
  public:
    BazDerived() : Base(25) { };
    ~BazDerived() { };
    int doBazThings() { return 2 * foo; };
}
```

As you can see, the `doThings` function in the **Base class** returns different results in each **Derived class** due to the different values of `foo`, while the `doOtherThings` function behaves identically across **all classes**.

When I wish to implement unit tests for these classes, the handling of `doThings`, `doBarThings` / `doBazThings` is clear to me - they need to be covered for each derived class. But how should `doOtherThings` be handled? Is it good practice to essentially duplicate the test case in both derived classes? The issue becomes worse if there are half a dozen functions like `doOtherThings`, and more **Derived classes**.

Comment: Are you sure only the dtor should be `virtual`?

Comment: @Deduplicator For the simplicity of the example, yes. The Base class is/should be abstract, with the derived classes providing additional functionality or specialized implementations. `BarDerived` and `Base` may have once been the same class. When a similar functionality was to be added the common part was moved into the Base class, with different specializations implemented in each Derived class.

Comment: In a less abstract example, imagive a class that writes standard-conforming HTML, but then it was decided that it should also be possible write HTML optimized for <Browser> besides the "vanilla" implementation (which does a few things differently, and does not support all functions provided by the standard). (Note: I am relieved to say that the real classes that lead to this questions have nothing to do with writing "browser-optimized" HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your tests for `BarDerived` you want to prove that all (public) methods of `BarDerived` work correctly (for the situations you have tested). Similarly for `BazDerived`.

The fact that some of the methods are implemented in a base class does not change this testing goal for `BarDerived` and `BazDerived`. That leads to the conclusion that `Base::doOtherThings` should be tested both in the context of `BarDerived` and `BazDerived` and that you get very similar tests for that function.

The advantage of testing `doOtherThings` for each derived class is that if the requirements for `BarDerived` change such that `BarDerived::doOtherThings` must return 24, then the test failure in the `BazDerived` testcase tells you that you might be breaking the requirements of another class.

Comment: And there's nothing stopping you from reducing duplication by factoring the common test-code into a single function which is called from both separate test cases.

Comment: IMHO this whole answer will only become a good one by adding clearly @SeanBurton's comment, otherwise it looks like a blatant violation of the DRY principle to me.

Answer (score 3):

> But how should doOtherThings be handled? Is it good practice to essentially duplicate the test case in both derived classes?

I would normally expect Base to have its own specification, which you can verify for any conforming implementation, including the derived classes.

```
void verifyBaseCompliance(const Base & systemUnderTest) {
    // checks that systemUnderTest conforms to the Base API
    // specification
}

void testBase () { verifyBaseCompliance(new Base()); }
void testBar () { verifyBaseCompliance(new BarDerived()); }
void testBaz () { verifyBaseCompliance(new BazDerived()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a conflict here.

You want to test the return value of `doThings()`, which relies on a **literal** (const value).

Any test you write for this is inherently going to boil down **testing a const value**, which is nonsensical.

---

To show you a more sensical example (I'm quicker with C#, but the principle is the same)

```
public class TriplesYourInput : Base
{
    public TriplesYourInput(int input)
    {
        this.foo = 3 * input;
    }
}
```

This class can be tested meaningfully:

```
var inputValue = 123;

var expectedOutputValue = inputValue * 3;
var receivedOutputValue = new TriplesYourInput(inputValue).doThings();

Assert.AreEqual(receivedOutputValue, expectedOutputValue);
```

This makes more sense to test. Its output is based on the input that you **chose** to give it. In such a case, you can give a class an arbitrarily chosen input, observe its output, and test if it matches your expectations.

Some examples of this testing principle. Notice that my examples always have direct control over what the input of the testable method is.

> - Test if `GetFirstLetterOfString()` return "F" when I input "Flater".
> - Test if `CountLettersInString()` returns 6 when I input "Flater".
> - Test if `ParseStringThatBeginsWithAnA()` returns an exception when I input "Flater".

All of these tests can input *whatever value they want*, as long as their expectations are in line with what they're inputting.

But if your output is decided by a constant value, then you're going to have to create a constant expectation, and then test if the first matches the second. Which is silly, this is either **always** or **never** going to pass; neither of which is a meaningful result.

Some examples of this testing principle. Notice that these examples have no control over at least *one* of the values that are being compared.

> - Test if `Math.Pi == 3.1415...`
> - Test if `MyApplication.ThisConstValue == 123`

These tests for **one** particular value. If you change this value, your tests will fail. In essence, you're not testing whether your logic works for any valid input, you're simply testing if someone is able to accurately **predict** an outcome which they have no control over.

That's essentially testing the test writer's knowledge of the business logic. It's not testing the code, but the writer themselves.

---

Reverting back to your example:

```
class BarDerived : public Base
{
  public:
    BarDerived() : Base(12) { };
    ~BarDerived() { };
    int doBarThings() { return foo + 1; };
}
```

Why does `BarDerived` always have a `foo` equal to `12`? What is the meaning of this?

And given that you've already decided this, what are you trying to gain by writing a test that confirms that `BarDerived` always has a `foo` equal to `12`?

This gets even worse if you start factoring in that `doThings()` can be overridden in a derived class. Imagine if `AnotherDerived` were to override `doThings()` so that it always returns `foo * 2`. Now, you're going to have a class which is hardcoded as `Base(12)`, whose `doThings()` value is 24. While technically testable, it is devoid of any contextual meaning. The test is not comprehensible.

I genuinely can't think of a reason to use this hardcoded value approach. **Even if there is a valid use case, I don't understand why you're trying to write a test to confirm this hardcoded value**. There is nothing to gain by testing if a constant value equals the same constant value.

Any test failure inherently proves that **the test is wrong**. There is no outcome where a test failure proves that the business logic is wrong. You're effectively unable to confirm that which tests are created to confirm in the first place.

The issue has nothing to do with inheritance, in case you were wondering. You just *happen* to have used a const value in the base class constructor, but you could've used this const value anywhere else and then it wouldn't be related to an inherited class.

---

**Edit**

There are cases where hardcoded values are not a problem. (again, sorry for the C# syntax but the principle is still the same)

```
public class Base
{
    public int MultiplyFactor;
    protected int InitialValue;

    public Base(int value, int factor)
    {
        this.InitialValue = value;
        this.MultiplyFactor= factor;
    }

    public int GetMultipliedValue()
    {
         return this.InitialValue * this.MultiplyFactor;
    }
}

public class DoublesYourNumber : Base
{
    public DoublesYourNumber(int value) :  base(value, 2) {}
}

public class TriplesYourNumber : Base
{
    public TriplesYourNumber(int value) : base(value, 3) {}
}
```

While the constant value (`2`/`3`) is still influencing the output value of `GetMultipliedValue()`, **the consumer of your class** still has control over it too!
In this example, meaningful tests can still be written:

```
var inputValue = 123;

var expectedDoubledOutputValue = inputValue * 2;
var receivedDoubledOutputValue = new DoublesYourNumber(inputValue).GetMultipliedValue();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedDoubledOutputValue , receivedDoubledOutputValue);

var expectedTripledOutputValue = inputValue * 3;
var receivedTripledOutputValue = new TriplesYourNumber(inputValue).GetMultipliedValue();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedTripledOutputValue , receivedTripledOutputValue);
```

- Technically, we're still writing a test that checks if the const in `base(value, 2)` matches the const in `inputValue * 2`.
- However, we are **at the same time** also testing that this class is correctly **multiplying any given value by this predetermined factor**.

The first bullet point isn't relevant to test. The second is!

Comment: As already mentioned, this is a rather over-simplified class structure. That said, let me refer to the perhaps less abstract example: Imagine a HTML-writing class. We all know that standard `<` and `>` braces that encapsulate the HTML tags. Unfortunately (due to insanity) a "specialized" browser uses `![{` and `}]!` instead, and Intitech decides that you need to support this browser in your HTML writer. For example you have the `getHeaderStart()` and `getHeaderEnd()` function that - until now - returned `<HEADER>` and `<\HEADER>`.

Comment: @CharonX You would still need to make the tag type (whether through an enum, or two string properties for the used tags, or anything equivalent) publically configurable in order to meaningfully test if the class correctly uses the tags. If you don't, your tests will be littered with undocumented constant values that are needed to get the test to work.

Comment: You could alter the class and functions by simply copy-pasting everything - once with `<`, the other with `![{`. But that would be rather bad. So you have each function insert the character(s) set in a variable in the places `<` and `>` would go, and create derived classes that - depending if they are standard-conform or insane, provide the appropiate `<HEADER>` or `![{HEADER}]!` Neither `getHeaderStart()` function is dependant on input and relies on the constant set during the construction of the derived class. Still, I would feel uneasy if you told me that testing them makes no sense...

Comment: @CharonX That's not the point. The point is that your output (which obviously decides if the test passes) is based on a value that the test itself has no control over. Otherwise, you should be testing an output value which does not rely on this hidden const. Your example code is testing this const value, not anything else. That is either incorrect, or oversimplified to a point of not showing the actual purpose of the output.

Comment: Does testing `getHeaderStart()` make sense or not?

Comment: @CharonX: Correction to my previous comment: It makes no sense to test a method of a class, if the test does not specify any parameters (to either the method or the class). If the test cannot meaningfully input (or influence) anything, it cannot make any meaningful conclusions about the output. If you test a `Base` method, your test shoud would **for every `Base` object**. Not just a subset of its derivations.